# XNA networking on windows

Tags: windows, networking, xna

1. What are XNA's builtin network functionalities?
2. Is it possible to use XNA's builtin network in windows? If so, any restrictions?

Answer (score 13):

If you use the [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.net(v=XNAGameStudio.31).aspx) classes, you are [restricted to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.net.networksessiontype(v=XNAGameStudio.31).aspx) local, subnet and Games for Windows Live (which means the developer having a Creator's club membership and players having a Silver/free GFWL membership).

However, as long as you're not planning on also supporting Xbox 360 or Zune (or Windows Phone 7), you can simply use the [System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.aspx) classes (though finding available games will be up to you and would require a server component).

See also:

- [Getting Started With Networked Games](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975642(v=XNAGameStudio.31).aspx)
- [How To: Create a Network Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975256(v=XNAGameStudio.31).aspx)
- [How To: Find and Join a Network Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975500(v=XNAGameStudio.31).aspx)

Comment: This pretty much covers it. Great answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use an external networking framework.
I found lidgren some months ago. I didn't look at it yet, but it seems quite good.

Maybe it's what you're looking for.

[Lidgren project](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/)

There are also code samples to start.