# XNA - Using System.Net in a Windows Proxy

Tags: c#, xna, xbox

I want to take a [separate Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414470/xna-networking-on-windows) a step further. In that post, it mentions that Windows versions of an XNA application can use the System.Net namespace and all its awesomeness for creating web requests. I also know that XNA applications (Windows and Xbox) can talk over the local network, sending packets back and forth.

I'm curious if I could have one assembly on my Windows machine that uses System.Net, and another assembly on my Xbox that talks to the Windows machine, and I could turn my Windows PC into a web proxy. I could then write a web browser, for instance, on my Xbox.

Internet <> Windows XNA Game using System.Net <> Xbox XNA Game Consumer

I have read that for a Windows application to talk to an Xbox application locally, the two need to have the same assembly GUID, which I can easily account for. However, I can't find out if the two assemblies have to be identical. And that's why I've come to Stackoverflow.

Can two different assemblies with the same assembly GUID talk to each other over a local network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like someone already did it [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/23486.aspx). The notable information is that if you ever published it, it wouldn't work anymore. But for your own use, yes it seems very possible to use SystemLink and a Proxy version of your "game" on your Windows machine.